# jquery are-you-sure fails to run, F12 says object doesnt support property or method

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Got the project from: https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure

In the MVC app, jquery is used for the datepicker and it all runs fine.  Am currently using the

```
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
```

And this works, it will warn EVERY time the page changes, clean/dirty, and even when saving the form.  The goal is to specifically check for the form=dirty, then warn of unsaved changes, but not if the 'Save' button is being clicked.    A good solution seems to be this jquery plugin, that I could not get to work.   Trying to add the jquery areYouSure() add-in to check for a clean/dirty form before leaving the page?  Any page can be exited, no dialog at all.  Cannot find what is missing or wrong.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {


 $('form').areYouSure();
```

at the top of the mvc edit.cshtml document:

```
<!-- CSS References Here -->

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/are-you-sure.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ays-beforeunload-shim.js"></script>
```

I manually downloaded and did a add/new item/ new javascript file, copied the contents from this projects github page into the manually named .js files in the /Scripts/ folder.  Project already had the jquery-1-10-2.js in there

tried but cannot make this work. when loading the form,  in IE, f12 breaks and points to:

```
  $('form').areYouSure();
```

Object doesn't support property or method 'areYouSure'

Answer (score 0):

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js", 
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.are-you-sure.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"));
```

The reference needed to be here.  it works just fine now.

Comment: The reason you see that error because jquery-1.10.2.js library is included twice: one is already in your MVC bundle that is often included in common _LayOut.cshtml file; one in your MVC